# Angular 2 could not load component till an action was triggered

Tags: angular, meteor, angular-meteor

I have a problem when trying to create routers for my app, it's using angular 2 and meteor.

Let's come to my point:
Like you see, the router was in fanpages, pre component was removed, but no new component loaded :|

[image]

It just load fanpages component when I move the mouse or click on this page

[image]

So, what's my fault? or any thing went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your code and not just screenshots

Comment: Sounds like code running outside appropriate zone.

Comment: more code please

Comment: I had similar problem in Safari, updating it to latest version fixes the issue. or add better support for polyfill